Apache Flink: SlidingProcessingTimeWindows with ProcessWindowFunction not producing expected output
So I have an extremely simple streaming pipeline setup using apache flink, streaming data from kinesis, I don't think this really matters but I am using AWS's Managed Flink Environment, that said here is my implementation.

Each individual event payload from stream
class Event {
 String deviceId;
 String metricName;
 Double value;
 // added for debugging - while I parse the record, the deserializer uses the current system time to automatically add this field.
 String receivedTimeStamp;
}


Streaming Pipeline
final DataStream<Event> stream = // create streaming kinesis source

// setting up an extremely simple pipeline
stream.keyBy(Event::getDeviceId)
                .window(SlidingProcessingTimeWindows.of(
                        /*Window length*/ Time.hours(2),
                        /*Slide length*/  Time.hours(1)))
                .process(new EventsWindowFunction());


List<TransformedEvent> - OUT of my ProcessWindowFunction
public class TransformedEvent {
    private String deviceId;
    private Double value;
    private String metricName;
    // added for debugging - this is simply read from Event item from each element in Iterable<Event> iterable
    String receivedTimeStamp;
}


ProcessWindowFunction (EventsWindowFunction extends ProcessWindowFunction<Event, List<TransformedEvent>, String, TimeWindow>)
@Override
    public void process(
            final String s,
            final Context context,
            final Iterable<Event> iterable,
            final Collector<List< TransformedEvent>> collector) throws Exception {
        // using this for logging
        final String deviceId = Iterables.get(iterable, 0).getDeviceId();
        final List<TransformedEvent> output = new ArrayList<>();
        StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false)
                .map(/* Transform raw Event to TransformedEvent*/)
                .forEach(output::add);
        // added logging here to print the entire output for the deviceId (keying by deviceId)
        collector.collect(output);
    }


Here is what I am noticing with the above implementation:
For lets say a deviceId ABC I am seeing the following output:
Output at 6AM (window from 4-6am)

List<TransformedEvent>

deviceId: ABC value: 0.79 metricName: MetricOne receivedTimeStamp: 5:07 AM
deviceId: ABC value: 0.12 metricName: MetricTwo receivedTimeStamp: 4:15 AM



Output at 7AM (window from 5-7am)

Nothing for deviceId: ABC

My Question

According to the documentation on sliding windows shouldn't MetricOne for deviceId ABC appear in 5-7am window ? As seen above it currently only shows up from 4-6am window and not in the subsequent window (ie 5-7am). But I also noticed that in the 4-6 am window it correctly included events from the previous window (ie 3-5am). So I'm confused.
I am almost certain I'm overlooking some caveats, so looking for any pointers whatsoever. Also the deviceId may not have emitted an event after the last event that was received at 5:07 AM.
Also as David Anderson always says if you are not seeing expected results switch to using "wallclock time/ingestion time" and I believe using SlidingProcessingTimeWindows should be automatically considering ingestion time ? I am suspecting I am misunderstanding something at this specific point, but only my speculation.


Windows are not created if there is no event!
In your example, and to keep things simple, let’s assume you started your pipeline at 4 am. Now just because you started at 4 does NOT mean a window is instantly created. A window will be created only when an event arrives.
In your case it arrives at 4:15. So your first window has range 4:15 — 6:15.
5:07 falls in this window but NOT in the second window that starts at 5:15 (ending at 7:15)
